# How to add/set icon to Arc.UserDialogs ActionSheet?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Arc.UserDialogs ActionSheet in my xamarin form app. But I am unable to attach a icons to the action sheet items. It asks a string value. I set image name but not working.

```
 UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheet(new ActionSheetConfig()
                            .SetTitle("Choose Type")
                            .Add("Default", null, "icon1.png")
                            .Add("E-Mail", null, "icon2.png")
                        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code in my VS, I can add/set icon to `Arc.UserDialogs ActionSheet` like the following screenshot.

[image]

You can put these picture in `drawable` folder in android

[image]

In IOS, 1. double-click the `Assets` folder like the following screenshot.

[image]

Then create `Image`(click the plus in the top-left), put the image in the `1x`
[image]

This is my demo(I test it in android, it is normal).
https://github.com/851265601/ToolbarItemDemo

Comment: i am getting 

*Unhandled Exception:
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0*

but images are there

Comment: Can you upload you demo?

Comment: Did you try to delete `obj` and `bin` folder in your project ,then rebuild it .

Comment: Do you want to know which icon you clicked? Then,you will make some actions?If so, you can `.add("Default", () =>DisplayAlert("Default" , "you choice Default ","ok") , "icon1.png");.add("E-Mail", () => DisplayAlert("E-Mail", "you choice E-Mail ", "ok"), "icon2.png"); `